# Xcode 6: Where is form factor toggle icon/button?

Tags: xcode, autolayout

I have searched on the forum and can't find this question or possible answer to it.

I am myself using Xcode 6 and doing a tutorial on auto layout for a simple iphone app on treehouse. Sadly the tutor is using Xcode 4. While I do have the auto layout menu buttons available to me on bottom right of screen, the form factor toggle button is not next to the auto layout menu, as it is on Xcode 4 where it is directly to the left of the auto layout menu.

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to enable the form factor button to appear here, or if there is an alternate way to toggle form factor and see different screen sizes without having to run the program every time?
MAybe it is gone now due to the extra screen sizes available now?

Appreciate help and please be patient, I am a newcomer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Assistant Editor->Preview->MainStoryboard there is a plus(+) button at the left bottom of the screen.There you 'll find how it will look like your storyboard for every device.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Found it! Thank you!!

Comment: Just a follow-up question. I have selected to see a preview of three different screen sizes but can't see all of them on screen. How can I delete two of the preview screen sizes so that I can see the other? When i click on a new screen size from list it is added to preview page, it does not change previous preview screen sizes.

Comment: If you choose one of them and press backspace it should be deleted.

Comment: If my answer helped you to solve your question, could you accept it please.

Comment: Accepted now - sorry, hadn't known about that feature here. Thanks again, you were seriously helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

With Xcode 6, you can go to Editor > Simulated Screen and select the device/orientation mode you want.